Writing ancient Complex Text Layout (CTL) text using Latex (the case of old Uyghur)
I want to write something in the Old Uyghur script. Unicode supports this script, and there is a well-developed font for this purpose: Noto Serif Old Uyghur. However, when I try to write using local text editors (LibreOffice Writer, GNOME Text Editor, etc.), the cursive joining rules are not applied to the characters. In contrast, using Google Fonts' online editor works perfectly. Is there a way to correctly write in the Old Uyghur script using XeLaTeX, LuaTeX, or another tool?
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.
As an example the text over Google Fonts' online Editor is as following:

However, using LibreOffice Writer the cursive joining rules are not correct:

@javier-bezos -> Thank you for your time and help. I tried your example, but the result still was without proper joining of characters. This is the logs of my lualatex:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023/Debian)  (format=lualatex 2024.12.19)  1 JAN 2025 08:44
restricted system commands enabled.
**uy.tex
(./uy.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
Lua module: luaotfload 2023-08-31 3.26 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/arslan/.texlive2023/texmf-var
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-08-19.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-
08-19.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.133
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/arslan/.texlive2023/texmf-var
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (/usr/share/texlive/tex
mf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2024/01/07 v24.1 The Babel package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\l@dumylang=\language2
Package babel Info: Non-standard hyphenation setup on input line 118.
\l@nohyphenation=\language3
\l@vietnamese=\language4
\l@hebrew=\language5
\l@ibycus=\language6
\l@greek=\language7
\l@monogreek=\language8
\l@ancientgreek=\language9
\babelcatcodetablenum=\catcodetable14
\bbl@pattcodes=\catcodetable15
)
\babel@savecnt=\count193
\U@D=\dimen140
\l@unhyphenated=\language10

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\bbl@attr@locale=\attribute4

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count194
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable16
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable17
)
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `Babel.pre_otfload_v' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `Babel.pre_otfload_h' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
\bbl@attr@dir=\attribute5
)
Package babel Info: You haven't specified a language as a class or package
(babel)             option. I'll load 'nil'. Reported on input line 4342.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/nil.ldf
Language: nil 2024/01/07 v24.1 Nil language
\l@nil=\language11
))
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'olduyghur' set to \l@nil
(babel)             (\language11). Reported on input line 17.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-01-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-01-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count195
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
))
Package: xparse 2023-10-10 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2022/01/15 2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count196
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count197
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen141
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen142
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen143

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
luaotfload | aux : font no 18 (nil) defines no feature for script latn with lang
uage dflt
luaotfload | aux : font no 19 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
with language dflt

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)' created
(fontspec)             for font 'NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Script=Latin,Language=nil,RawFeature={fam
ily=rm}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf]:mode=node;script=la
tn;language=dflt;+tlig;family=rm;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 


No file uy.aux.

\openout1 = uy.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 2
4.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.


Package babel Info: The following font families will use the default
(babel)             settings for all or some languages:
(babel)             * \sffamily = lmss
(babel)               [lmsans10-regular]:+tlig;
(babel)             * \ttfamily = lmtt
(babel)               [lmmono10-regular]:
(babel)             There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, but
(babel)             'babel' will no set Script and Language, which could
(babel)             be relevant in some languages. If your document uses
(babel)             these families, consider redefining them with \babelfont.
(babel)             Reported on input line 24.

Removing  `Babel.pre_otfload_h' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `Babel.math_box_dir' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `Babel.pre_otfload_h' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)/m/
n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)/m
/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)/m/n --> TU/NotoSer
ifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)/m
/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)/b
/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)/m/n --> TU/NotoSer
ifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)/b/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(0)/
b/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 24.
luaotfload | aux : font no 18 (nil) defines no feature for script ougr
luaotfload | aux : font no 19 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
with language dflt

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(1)' created
(fontspec)             for font 'NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Script=Old
(fontspec)             Uyghur,RawFeature={family=rm}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf]:mode=node;script=la
tn;language=dflt;+tlig;family=rm;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 


Overfull \hbox (31.37677pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--35
[]\TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(1)/m/n/10   
  
   
 
[]


Overfull \hbox (0.55673pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--35
\TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(1)/m/n/10  
   
   
 
[]


Overfull \hbox (3.93343pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--35
\TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(1)/m/n/10   
   
 
 
[]


Overfull \hbox (8.01009pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--35
\TU/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf(1)/m/n/10   
    
   
   
[]

[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./uy.aux)
***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
4063 strings out of 476553
100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
414 words of node memory still in use:
  3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 8 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
  avail lists: 2:43,3:12,4:2,5:23,6:2,7:990,9:30,10:1
26081 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
22 fonts using 1412447 bytes
80i,5n,97p,394b,213s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</home/arslan/.local/share/fonts/NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf>
Output written on uy.pdf (1 page, 10634 bytes).

PDF statistics: 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)

The output is:


Please, edit your post and add a minimal example with a short text in Old Uyghur, as well as an image with the expected result.

LuaLaTeX + fontspec with mode=harf would probably work, and I think that ConTeXt has pretty good Arabic support too.

Shouldn’t this script be typeset vertically?

Box and rotate (using a minipage, say) could be a quickish solution. Quickest way of all is manually rotating the printout. I think a TikZ loop placing rotated boxed words onto the page as an array could be the (c)leanest  generic solution, much like vertical Chinese.

I think I managed to typeset the text with babel and after some tests with different font features. I'm preparing an example, and hopefully I’ll post it in a few hours or perhaps tomorrow. I presume you want horizontal typesetting (from Unicode: “Although the script is traditionally laid out vertically in columns that run left to right, horizontal orientation facilitates the handling of Old Uyghur in multilingual contexts”).

Here is a preliminary solution, which shows Old Uyghur typesetting is certainly possible (with an up-to-date TeXLive).
It uses LuaLaTeX with babel, which fully supports this engine. If you remove the \babelcharproperty command and set bidi=bidi instead of bidi=basic, it works with XeLaTeX, too (very likely with some restrictions). The recommended engine is the former.
A more detailed solution would require more info on what you actually want: a whole document in Old Uyghur?, just some examples in this script?...
[Edit. With a non up-to-date TeXLive, you may need activate explicitly the Harfbuzz renderer, with \babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf}]
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}

% A low level setting, because babel doesn’t include (yet)
% Old Uyghur in the list of RTL scripts:
\makeatletter
\addto\bbl@rscripts{,Old Uyghur,}
\makeatother

% Directionality is missing, too, but here a high level is
% available:
\babelcharproperty{"10F70}["10FAF]{direction}{r}

% Declare a new language. This seems to be enough, although a
% more complete setup is also possible.
\babelprovide[script=Old Uyghur]{olduyghur}

% Font version is 1.004:
\babelfont{rm}
  % [Style=Alternate]  % Optional
  {NotoSerifOldUyghur-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{olduyghur}

        
        
         
        
            
          
        ‌

\end{document}


